# Set New Value for Variation Product Stock Quantity in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to set the total number of products as stock quantity in variation products and I don't know which hook to use.

I'm currently using the `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object` hook and I don't know if it's correct, I guess I won't be able to get out of this without help.

Also here I tried `wc_update_product_stock` and `set_stock_quantity` as functions, neither of them give any results, so I thought the hook might not be correct.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'set_new_variation_stock_quantity' );
function set_new_variation_stock_quantity( $product ) {
      global $product;
      $total = 0;
      
      // Get variation product total quantity
      if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        foreach ( $product->get_visible_children() as $variationId ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variationId );
            $total += $variation->get_stock_quantity();
           }
       }
            // Just for variation product
            if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
                
        // Try wc_update_product_stock function
        $product = wc_update_product_stock( $product, $total, 'set', 'false' );
        return $product;
        
        // Try other set_stock_quantity
        $product = $product->set_stock_quantity( $product, $total);
        $product->save();
        return $product;
     }
  return $product;
}
```